# isEmpty() checking in mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

How to write `junit` for the statement

```
if (!messageMap.isEmpty())
```

where `messageMap` is a `TreeMap`.
I wrote as follows,

```
PowerMockito.when(!messageMap.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);
```

But this code not working.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you are asking for.

When you just want to ensure that your production call **makes** that call to `isEmpty()` and then the ideal way of testing is to simply **pass** empty and non-empty maps to your code under test.

Meaning; you do something like:

```
@Test
public void testWithEmptyMap() {
  UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest(Collections.emptyMap());
  assertThat(underTest.foo(), is(whatever));

@Test
public void testWithFilledMap() {
  UnderTest underTest = new UnderTest(Collections.singletonMap(key, value));
  assertThat(underTest.foo(), is(somethingElse));
```

In other words: the **best** way of testing goes without mocking. You give your code under test different input; and you **assert** that you get the expected results for the different input values.

But of course, sometimes you have to **control** how mocked objects passed to your code under test behave; and in that case, yes, you could actually do create a messageMap mock and configure it like:

```
Mockito.when(messageMap.isEmpty()).thenReturn(false);
```

But: that would be bad practice. You only mock objects that you can't control easily. A map is super-easy to control; simply by pushing some content into it (or leaving it empty). So instead of passing a mocked map configured to be empty or contain a value ... pass a real map; either empty or containing some values!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you shouldn't mock any util classes(List, Map or Set).You can write test case by following below two approaches

Approach 1: If you want messageMap.isEmpty() should return true then create empty tree object as below.

```
Map<K, V> messageMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

Approach 2: If you want messageMap.isEmpty() should return false then create tree object as below.

```
    Map<K, V> messageMap = new TreeMap<>();
     messageMap.put(k1,v1);
     messageMap.put(k2,v2);
```

and just pass messageMap object to actual class method, it should work fine.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: List, Map or Set are Util classes?

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to mock the call or to make an assertion?

In case of mock you can write:

```
Mockito.when(messageMap.isEmpty()).thenReturn(false);
```

In case of assertion:

```
Assert.assertTrue(messageMap.isEmpty());
```